# Regular Expression oddity, why does this happen?

Tags: c#, regex

This simple regular expression matches the text of `Movie`. Am I wrong in reading this as "Q repeated zero or more times"? Why does it match, shouldn't it return false?

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("Q*");
        string input = "Movie";
        if (regex.IsMatch(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yup.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nope.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `\Q{0,}` and see if that works for you

Comment: Yes it matches, matched nothing, the `zero time's`. Print the match result to see that it matched nothing. You give the engine the _option_ to match things with the `*` `?` `{0,n}` quantifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are saying correctly, it means “Q repeated **zero** or more times”. I this case, it’s zero times, so you are essentially trying to match `""` in your input string. As [`IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx) doesn’t care *where* it matches, it can match the empty string anywhere within your input string, so it returns true.

If you want to make sure that the whole input string has to match, you can add `^` and `$`: `"^Q*$"`.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^Q*$");
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("Movie")); // false
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("QQQ")); // true
Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("")); // true
```

Comment: `^Q*$`'s negative equivalent `^[^Q]+$`. I guess an empty string could be valid but its hardly ever validated with a regex this way.

Comment: @sln I’m not sure what you are trying to say with that.

Comment: What's the purpose of matching an empty string?

Comment: @sln There are many valid use cases where accepting an empty match is absolutely fine and desired. Validation is one example (e.g. “I don’t care if you enter a value, but when you do, use the correct format”). Also, it’s obvious that OP knows that `Q*` can match the empty string, so it’s very likely desired behavior. I really don’t get your point here.

Comment: `Q*` matches non-empty strings as well. He didn't use the begin/end anchors. Required _input_ has no option for empty string, optional input probably should not be validated. If it were needing to be validated, a singular positive check for invalidity is in order. As it is, most input requiring a strict format should be event driven, not allowing invalid keypress or pasting of invalid char's. Is this a valid point or am I way off base?

Answer (score 2):

You are right in reading this regex as `Q` repeated 0 or more times. The thing with that is the `0`. When you try a regex, it will try to find any successful match.

The only way for the regex to match the string is to try matching an empty string (0 times), which appears anywhere in-between the matches, and if you didn't know that before, yes, regex can match empty strings between characters. You can try:

```
(Q*)
```

To get a capture group and use `.Matches` and `Groups[1].Value` to see what has been captured. You'll see that it's an empty string.

Usually, if you want to check the existence of a character, you don't use regex, but use [`.Contains`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/contains). Otherwise, if you do want to use regex, you'd drop the quantifier, or use one which matches at least one particular character.